# postgresql data formatting while querying

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting

i am new to sql in postgreqsl my table looks like

| city | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nyc | max | smith |
| nyc | will | xxx |
| nyc | sam | 123 |
| wdc | stacy | xxx |
| wdc | kim | xxx |
| cap | john | xxx |
| cap | will | xxx |

**output should be like**

| city | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nyc | max | smith |
|  | will | xxx |
|  | sam | 123 |
| wdc | stacy | xxx |
|  | kim | xxx |
| cap | john | xxx |
|  | will | xxx |

any help is appreciated...
Regards

Comment: You should handle such a thing in the presentation layer of your application. Relations don't work this way.

Comment: Please explain how you want the rows ordered.  The format you want depends entirely on the ordering of the rows and that is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This type of formatting is usually handled on application side. However, it *can* be done in SQL, using `order by` and window functions:

```
select
    case when row_number() over(partition by city order by fname, lname) = 1
        then city
    end as city,
    fname, 
    lname
from mytable
order by city, fname, lname
```